# How to make the bot respond for only one "event" the is present in the sentence, and no two

Tags: javascript, json, discord, bots, discord.js

It's complicated, but see the exemple:

I declared this event:

```
client.on('message', async message => { 
if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("megumin"))
 {
    message.channel.send("What's up?");
}
});
```

But I declared too this event:

```
client.on('message', async message => { 
if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("thanks megumin"))
 {
    message.channel.send("We are welcome UwU");
}
});
```

When I put in the chat: "thanks megumin", the bot make the two events! I want her to answer only "thanks megumin", and no aswen the "megumin" in the sentence...
Someone can help me, plese?

Thank you @Levi_OP!

Comment: Read about this https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using two client.on's you should combine it into one.

```js
client.on('message', async message => { 
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("thanks megumin")) {
    message.channel.send("We are welcome UwU");
  } else if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("megumin")) {
      message.channel.send("What's up?");
  }
});
```

Comment: If it's the answer to you question, could you mark it as the answer?